# Nullpointer exception when setting bitmap in Asynctask

Tags: android, facebook, imageview

I've been playing around with the facebook SDK.
Trying to pull information about user and images and so on. 
The problem I struggeling with is trying to fetch the profilepicture for the user and setting it in my own custom view.

Here goes:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wingman, container, false);
AsyncTaskRunner bitmapJob = new AsyncTaskRunner(main.getContext(),v);
bitmapJob.execute(GlobalVariables.getUser().getId());
```

And here is my asyncTaskRunner class:

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask{

```
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Context mContext;
    private View rootView;

    public AsyncTaskRunner(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.rootView=rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bitmap = null; 

        //Fetch facebook pic
        URL image_value;
        try {
            image_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+GlobalVariables.getUser().getId()+"/picture?width=350&height=350" );
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Debug","onPostExecute");
        RoundedImageView rImgView = (RoundedImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.roundedImageViewProfil);
        Log.d("Debug","result: " + result);
        if(result != null){
            Log.d("Debug","Try to set");
            rImgView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Debug","didnt work");
            rImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp);
        }           
    }
}
```

And here is the debug-messages:

```
03-17 20:55:44.465: D/Debug(20080): result: android.graphics.Bitmap@42661550
03-17 20:55:44.465: D/Debug(20080): Try to set
03-17 20:55:44.465: D/AndroidRuntime(20080): Shutting down VM
03-17 20:55:44.465: W/dalvikvm(20080): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41540ba8)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080): Process: com.thorne.wingman, PID: 20080
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at com.thorne.wingman.Wingman$AsyncTaskRunner.onPostExecute(Wingman.java:116)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at com.thorne.wingman.Wingman$AsyncTaskRunner.onPostExecute(Wingman.java:1)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-17 20:55:44.465: E/AndroidRuntime(20080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Been lurking around the forum and I can't find any solutions to my problem. 
What is throwing the nullexception?

BR

Comment: whatever is at `Wingman.java:116` is null, probably your imageview

Comment: probably the bitmap is null when the onPost is executed.

Comment: how can the imageview be null? I pass my view to asyncTask and all.

Comment: THe image view can be null if the id doesn't exist in the layout, or the activity isn't running anymore, or if the activity's content view hasn't been set.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan: I've tried to inflate:    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.wingman, null);
   RoundedImageView rImgView = (RoundedImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.roundedImageViewProfil); No nullpointer exception but the Imageview wont update..

Answer (score 0):

Exception at:   rImgView.setImageBitmap(result);
Looks like rImgView is null.
Maybe the rootView being passed in is not for the correct layout where you want this to go?
Why not just fund that RoundedImageView before starting the AsyncTask and pass it in instead?